# Spring Batch - Don't write to file (or delete file) in case of any exception

Tags: spring-batch

Is it possible to not write data to a file in case there are any exceptions present or what would be the best way to delete said file in case any errors occur?

I'm currently using a custom writer that extends the FlatFileItemWriter to write data, I encountered a problem in which a validation fails in my custom Processor and I throw a custom Exception and the step exit status is marked as FAILED as expected, however there is some partial data in the file that I'm writing to, as a requirement this file can't contain partial data, it should be all the data when there are no errors, in case there are any errors, be it in the Reader, Processor or Writer then the file should't be generated at all.

I can't skip or filter the record that fails validation, because any missing records in this file will be treated as deleted, which might not be the case.

So how can I make sure that any file that was being written to is Deleted in case of any error encountered in the step's process?

I found a solution that feels kind of hacky in which I implement `StepExecutionListener` in my writer and do the following:

`this.errorDetected` is just a flag in my writer that is set to true when any validation fails.

```
    @Override
    ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        ExitStatus exitStatus;
        if (this.errorDetected || stepExecution.exitStatus == ExitStatus.FAILED) {
            if (this.fileImWritingTo.getFile().exists()) {
                this.fileImWritingTo.getFile().delete();
            }
            exitStatus = ExitStatus.FAILED.addExitDescription("Validation failed");
            return exitStatus;
        } else {
            return stepExecution.exitStatus;
        }
    }
```

Is this a good solution? Or would you recommend something better?

Thanks!

Comment: Using a listener is one option. Another option is to use a separate steps that deletes the file in case the previous step failed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It seems easier to just use the listener in my case, since I can easily pass it a reference of the resource I need to delete. I wanted to verify that there wasn't an existing option like "shouldDeleteIfError" like the existing "shouldDeleteIfExists" option for the FlatFileItemWriter

Answer (score 0):

what about with 'noSkip', I used with database and worked fine

```
@Bean
public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                  FlatFileItemWriter<Transaction> writer,
                  FlatFileItemReader<Transaction> reader) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<Transaction, Transaction> chunk(5)
            .reader(reader)
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer)
            .faultTolerant()
            .noSkip(CustomException.class)
            .build();
}
```

The processor something like:

```
public class TransactionItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Transaction, Transaction> {
@Override
public Transaction process(Transaction transaction) throws Exception {
    if (transaction.getType().equals("fail")) {
        throw new CustomException();
    }
    return transaction;
}
```

}

And in the flow definition of the job create a clean up step

```
 @Bean
public Job batchJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
                    Step cleanUpStep,
                    Step mainStep) {

    return jobBuilderFactory.get(BatchConstant.BATCH_NAME)
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(mainStep)
            .from(mainStep).on("FAILED").to(cleanUpStep)
            .end()
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this doesn't work in my case, the step actually does stop and doesn't skip any items after I throw the exception. The main problem is that I'm writing in chunks of 100, so the first 100 get written correctly, then when I'm processing the next batch of 100 I throw the exception, but the first 100 that were processed correctly never get "rolledback"

Comment: Maybe you can add a Clean Up Step on FAILED status of the main step (I updated the code). Probably It's a little bit cleaner. If I read the code, I dont expect that a listener executes a clean step, this way I'm aware that if main step fails, a clean up task will be executed